# Logic Controller - assigned value not working

Tags: jmeter

[image]

If I put value as '0' on Switch value what would be the result, where as I put "1" what would be the result here. Is the any possible to put double string value in the SWITCH VALUE field?

From below screen shot , I tried with single strings like Yahoo,Hotmail. It is working, but if I give double trying with comma it is not working.

Comment: You cannot specify 2 values at once. Maybe rephrase your question to specify what you want to achieve instead.

Answer (score 0):

Switch Controller doesn't work this way. If you want to choose a value from "Yahoo" and "Hotmail" randomly each iteration you can use i.e. [__chooseRandom()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#chooseRandomsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-0-1-font-sup) function available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) like:

```
${__chooseRandom(Yahoo,Hotmail,)}
```

or if you don't want the plugins you can achieve the same with JMeter's built-in functions like [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript)

```
${__javaScript(var mails=["Yahoo"\,"Hotmail"]\,rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*mails.length);mails[rnd];,)}
```

The result will be identical in both cases:

[image: JMeter Switch Random Demo]

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide for comprehensive information on the domain.